# HH:MM:SS:Msec to HH:MM:SS in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a stored procedure which update a table based on such calculation and the calculation is done as column name (`Calendatedate`) - (`Current System Date Time`) and update this information to a column (`TimeSpent`) and display the value in  `Hh:Mm:SS:Msec` format.

The query is working fine but I want to update it in such a way so that the time spent should be only `HH:MM:SS` format. Please help me that how I remove that `Msec` from the time spent.

```
CREATE procedure St_Proc_UpdateTimeSpent        
@timeEntryID int,        
@status int output        
as begin         
set nocount on;        
declare @Date dateTime;        
set @Date=GETDATE(); 
    update Production set TimeSpent=(SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),DateAdd(SS,Datediff(ss,CalendarDate, @Date)%(60*60*24),0),114)),  
    IsTaskCompleted=1       
    where productionTimeEntryID=@timeEntryID         
    set @status=1;        
    return @status;        
end
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: Wouldn't it be enough for you to do a `CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),....)` instead of `CONVERT(VARCHAR(20)...`?

Comment: What data type is `TimeSpent`?  If it's a `VARCHAR()`, why aren't you using `DATETIME`?  If you are using a `DATETIME` then you don't try to set the formatting in the table *(A `DATETIME` doesn't have a format, it's a binary type)*, instead you set the formating when you select the values out of the table (or, even better, in your presentation layer) by converting the value to a string and chosing a format at that point in time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use style 108 instead of 114 in the `CONVERT` function to get only the `hh:mm:ss`:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.St_Proc_UpdateTimeSpent        
     @timeEntryID int,        
     @status int output        
AS BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON;

   DECLARE @Date DATETIME;
   SET @Date = GETDATE(); 

   UPDATE dbo.Production 
   SET TimeSpent = CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), DATEADD(SS, DATEDIFF(ss, CalendarDate, @Date)%(60*60*24),0), 108),  
       IsTaskCompleted = 1
   WHERE  
       productionTimeEntryID = @timeEntryID         

   SET @status = 1;

   RETURN @status;        
END
```

See the [excellent MSDN documentation on CAST and CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) for a comprehensive list of all supported styles when converting `DATETIME` to `VARCHAR` (and back)

BTW: SQL Server 2008 also introduced a [`TIME` datatype](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677243.aspx) which would probably be a better fit than a `VARCHAR` to store your `TimeSpent` values ... check it out!

Comment: You're assuming that `TimeSpent` is a `VARCHAR()`.  I've seen people use `CAST/CONVERT` to try to format the contents of a `DATETIME` field far to often to trust that assumption ;)

Comment: @Dems: yes, I assume `VARCHAR` since that's the target type of the `CONVERT` call and the OP is talking about a specific "format" (which really only makes sense with `VARCHAR`) - but you're right, that doesn't really mean anything, I know :-)